# Создание сайта-агрегатора

Tags: python, html, css, sql, django

Я новичок в создании сайтов и не представляю, как можно реализовать сайт-агрегатор.

Допустим, есть несколько сайтов университетов. Я хочу чтобы мой сайт собирал информацию об абитуриентах (их ФИО; название университета, в который подали документы; баллы за экзамены и т.д.). Всё это для того, чтобы можно было по ФИО пробивать список университетов, в которые были поданы документы от этого человека.

Как я понимаю, это работает по такому же принципу, как, например, сайт, продающий авиабилеты: собирает все предложения авиакомпаний в один единый сайт.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать.

Спасибо!

Comment: Точно так же, как и обычный сайт, только ещё написать к нему какой-нибудь парсер, который будет собирать данные из интересующих вас сайтов и класть в базу

Comment: Думаю для начала нужно создать парсер для сбора инфы с этих сайтов, сохранить все данные в файл (csv, json ). После подключиться к базе банных и занести все данные из файла в бд. После подключить эту бд к вашему сайту. Создать модель с настройкой сортировки и у же на сайте можно делать поиск.

Answer (score 0):

Для реализации сайта лучшим решением будет CMS OpenCart (OcStore).
Там уже налажены связи с базами данных MySQL и будет проще настраивать парсеры.